# How do you fire up an activity from sleep on event with cyborg?

Tags: android, cyborg

I have an activity with a service that keeps the app alive even after you kill it (unless you force close it) and it keeps getting events (in my case from firebase)

Now I want to fire up an activity in case of a specific event change from firebase. how to do it with cyborg?

Comment: https://github.com/nu-art/cyborg-core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ApplicationLauncher.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
cyborg.startActivity(intent);
```

using the cyborg default activity works..